# How do I load all my location based content into google maps

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ipad

I am writing an iPad application that uses the MapKit control.

How do I get all my content into Google Maps. i.e. I have a bunch of locations along with photos, video, audio and various other information.

So when the iPad user loads my App and zooms into a certain place in the world I want my Annotations to be visible and when they touch the pins they get access to more information etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var mp200 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dv200m'), myOptions);
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(tLat, tLon);
var mrk2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos, map: mp200, title: 'bla bla', icon: '/images/twitter.png' });
```

Comment: What language are you using?  My app is written in Objective C?

Comment: it's javascript, i thought you were building a iphone web app.